# How may I know the coordinate (longitude and latitude) of a vector layer using PyGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have a vector layer that has multiple polygons. What I ultimately want to do is to generate many small images of the layer (imagine putting a grid over the layer and export each square of the grid as an image). I have been using the research tools -> create grid plus atlas. But since I am now trying to automating the process using PyQGIS (so that I do not need to repeat doing it for the other cities), I am thinking of using a for loop to pan around in the layer. To do that, I need to know the coordinate of the 4 corners of the bounding box that contains all features in the layer.

I do not think there is a method in QgsVectorLayerUtils or QgsVectorLayer to do that directly. Is there any other way to do it?

I already have the code for the for loop. Now I want to get x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max from the layer (not hard-coded like now).

```
        x_min = 103.777667
        y_min = 1.312618

        x_max = 103.785963
        y_max = 1.319890
        x = x_min 
        y = y_min 


        while x < x_max:
            y = y_min 
            while y < y_max:
                if someCheck():                    
                    self._pan([x,y])
                    self._export(self.path + 'trainB/', n)
                    n += 1
                y = y+ 0.001
            x = x+ 0.001
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please add some code to your question so we can see what you've done so far

Comment: Hi Ian, I have added more to my question. Can you have a look?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Sounds like you want to [generate an atlas](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html). No need for pyqgis

Comment: Thanks BERA for your advice. I have been using atlas. I thought pyqgis while be easier to automate the process.